# nodejs websocket server ip localhost --> openshift

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket, openshift, unityscript

I am trying to migrate my nodejs websocket server from localhost to OpenShift. I managed to get the server running in openshift, but now I am having problems trying to connect to it from my Unity 3D client.

Server code:

```
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

console.log(server_port);
console.log(server_ip_address);

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
    , wss = new WebSocketServer({ host: server_ip_address, port: server_port });
```

The server outputs an ip 127.13.159.1 and a port 8080, but when I try to connect from Unity client using this ip and port it says "Error: The WebSocket connection has already been closed."

I am using this package in Unity for websockets https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38367

```
new WebSocket(new Uri("ws://127.13.159.1:8080"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to your application using websockets you need to use your ws://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000 or wss://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8443 (for secure websockets)